# Where to set angular strictness flags that configure how strict strictTemplates is?

Tags: angular, typescript, static-analysis, strict

I am currently converting our application to strictTemplates, and we are comming up with a huge amount of errors, some of them are more relevant than others.

So i wanted to configure the strictness of the angular type checker, and found this strictness flags in the documentation.

https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors

Here are some examples from the docs

> strictInputTypes  Whether the assignability of a binding expression to the @Input() field is checked. Also affects the inference of directive generic types.
>
> strictInputAccessModifiers    Whether access modifiers such as private/protected/readonly are honored when assigning a binding expression to an @Input(). If disabled, the access modifiers of the @Input are ignored; only the type is checked. This option is false by default, even with strictTemplates set to true.
>
> strictNullInputTypes  Whether strictNullChecks is honored when checking @Input() bindings (per strictInputTypes). Turning this off can be useful when using a library that was not built with strictNullChecks in mind.

[...]

The only question I could not answer was where to set them... So in which file should this flags configured, and how?

I searched the internet for a solution but did only find a huge swath of articles on how to enable --strict and what the benefits are.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates), you have to set them in the `tsconfig.json` file, inside the `angularCompilerOptions` field.

Comment: Believe me I searched quite some time, and then found the solution at the same time as you. Sometimes the solution is easier than one thinks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in this post: https://www.angular.love/en/2021/09/02/angular-compilation-restrictions-overview/

Just put these flags below the strictTemplates option:

in `tsconfig.app.json`

```
   ...
     "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "strictNullChecks": true,
     },
     "angularCompilerOptions": {
       "strictTemplates": true,
       "strictInputTypes": true,
       "strictNullInputTypes": true
     }
    }
```